# Three.js getting position of an object in it's object space after rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to move the object along 'x' axis, rotate it by 90 degrees, and move it again along 'x' axis (which is now the 'z' global axis). The path of this movement should create a right angle then. This is my code which moves the object:

```
if(Math.abs(myObject.position.x - newX) > 0.01){
  myObject.translateX(0.1);
}
```

The problem, however, is that the object moves in the right direction (along it's 'x' axis) but the value `myObject.position.x` is not changing. Instead, it's 'z' position is changing. Base on that I can say that `myObject.position` returns it's world position, not the one relative to the object space. I've been experimenting with `localToWorld` and `worldToLocal` methods, but no luck so far. How can I make sure it moves in the right direction after rotation?

EDIT:
I've added `group` to my code like this:

```
group = new THREE.Group();
group .add(myObject);
scene.add(group);
```

My moving function looks like this:

```
if(Math.abs(group.position.x - newX) > 0.01){
   group.translateX(0.1);
}
```

And the rotating function:

```
if(Math.abs(myObject.rotation.y - newRot) > 0.02){
   myObject.rotateY(0.02);
}
```

Comment: Put your object in a [`THREE.Group`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group). Rotate the object, but move the group.

Comment: The above comment is correct

Comment: @Rabbid76 I've done it, but now the object moves along the 'old' x-axis (so it's new 'z'). I edited my original post.

Comment: So the problem is that after rotation it moves in the same direction as before it. In both cases I call 'translateX' on it. So it should move like (move forward, rotate, move left) instead it moves (move forward, rotate, move forward) what means it keeps moving along it's orginal x-axis.

Comment: Btw. I just noticed that my object is actually a Three.Group() as well. Can that influence the outcome?

Comment: I think I am on a good path. I believe it has to do with 'lookAt()' method. I am trying to rotate the object using this function.

Comment: No, I was wrong. LookAt didn't help.